# attribute or String new line in var object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, string

[image]

hello im currently express this var with

```
 var consultRemark = "1. Valid Date : 1 Week , Based on Quote Date  \r\n  " + " 2. Payment Condition : Cash only Conditions may Apply. \r\n " + "3. Period : may changed after customer's deal.";
    var action = component.get("c.getInitData");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<aura:unescapedHTML>` tag should be used here. And instead of `\r\n`, use HTML tag `<br/>` for line breaks.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification

```
 var consultRemark = "1. Valid Date : 1 Week , Based on Quote Date  <br/> 2. Payment Condition : Cash only Conditions may Apply. <br/> 3. Period : may changed after customer's deal.";
component.set("v.auraAttributeVar",consultRemark);

<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.auraAttributeVar}" />
```

To put new lines in Lightning:inputRichText, replace `<br/>` with `<p/>`

```
var consultRemark = "1. Valid Date : 1 Week , Based on Quote Date  <p/> 2. Payment Condition : Cash only Conditions may Apply. <p/> 3. Period : may changed after customer's deal.";
    component.set("v.auraAttributeVar",consultRemark);

<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.auraAttributeVar}" placeholder="Type something interesting"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but is there any way to express this directly on a lightning:input markup?

Comment: I dont think you can put new line in `lightning:input` component. However you can use `lightning:inputRichText` component for this. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: i think this is clear solution for putting a new line. Thanks bunch